# Get HmacSHA256 key for Instagram private api

Tags: android, instagram-api

Many of us are using cracked Instagram API (https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/). This API needs some calls to be signed as following:

```
        byte[] keyBytes = GenericConstants.SECRET_KEY.getBytes();
        SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "HmacSHA256");
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        mac.init(signingKey);
        byte[] rawHmac = mac.doFinal(json.getBytes());
        byte[] hexBytes = new Hex().encode(rawHmac);
        String signetJson =  String(hexBytes, "UTF-8");
```

And request sent as `signetJson.NORMAL_JSON`.

The problem is that `SECRET_KEY` is different for every Instagram version, is there a way to get it from Android device, or does anybody have one to share? ;)

Answer (score 1):

You will need an gikdbg and Android running ART.

From gikdbg, attach com.instagram.android process and look for a module called libstrings.so

Set a break point just above the crypto_auth_hmacsha256_init where strlen is called, run in order to hit the break point. From there, extract the key from the memory via register memory address, by following the dump.

[image: IG Key]